# How to preserve the Recently Used Symbols in Microsoft Office 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

In several applications of the MS Office suite (e.g. Word, Outlook), there is a menu option `Insert > Ω Symbol ∨` that gives a flyout of recently used symbols.  The dialog from the `More symbols...` option under this flyout also has a "Recently used symbols:" list.

Since upgrading to Office 365, these lists do not persist after the application is closed.  At the next session, they revert to *symbols commonly used by others* (e.g. international currencies).

Is there a configuration option that will preserve *my* recently used symbols in the list?

---

I am using **Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20384) 64-bit**

Update:  It seems that the list is not reset every time the application is restarted, so this suggests there is some other automatic process (Office update?) that is resetting it occasionally.  If I detect a pattern I will update.

Comment: Is this issue resolved now? If so, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Comment: @Christy Neither of the answers posted so far resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Office does not provide a list of your recently-used symbols,
so below are some ideas for improving the interface:

- Use the "Shortcut Key..." button at the bottom of the dialog.
  Using the "Press New Shortcut Key" field, you can specify a shortcut key
  that will insert this symbol.
- Use the "AutoCorrect..." button to assign a character sequence that
  will be automatically replaced/corrected to this symbol.
  Enter the sequence in the "Replace..." field.
- The old and simple way is to create a document that will hold all your
  often-used symbols, from which you may copy-paste.
- The last and most adventurous method is to create your own font to
  contain your symbols.
  See the article
  [How to Create Your Own Fonts and Characters on Windows](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-your-own-fonts-symbols-characters-windows/).

Added by the poster:

- Use the Windows "Character Map" which can be searched by
  the partial name of the symbol, using the "Search for" field and
  the "Search" button.
- The built-In Windows Emoji Keyboard can be accessed by
  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (Windows and dot).

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose we may never know why the list called "Recently used symbols" does not actually contain such symbols.  I have been using the shortcut keys for some already.  I still use the old Windows Character Map which can be searched by Unicode name.  Windows 10 also has the "Windows + period" menu, which has *some* of the symbols.  BTW I don't think "adventurous" is quite the word I'd use for your last method.  The only time I went to the trouble of creating a font, I was also [creating a language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) that needed it.

Comment: You could use the Windows Feedback Hub to report as bug that the "Recently used symbols" list does not actually contain them.

Answer (score 0):

### The box works as expected in my Office 365. Here is a screenshot from Word.

[image: screenshot]

That was taken after reopening Word. Then I opened PowerPoint and checked; the same symbols appear in recently used symbols.

Perhaps some other program is interfering with the function or saving.

Which version of Office 365 are you using? `File` > `Account`

Do you have any Addins?

You could always try [repairing Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).